# How do I make a twitter scheduler on drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, social-network

I basically want to make a twitter scheduler. What it does is ,it fetches the old tweets from my twitter account and queues them so that I can schedule them to be sent at a later time. 
So the **three** main jobs of this would be --

1. Fetch tweets from my account.
2. Queue them
3. Schedule them to be tweeted as per the user.

Could someone please tell me what all modules Id require for the same?

Thanks 
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a node type ‘Tweet’
2. Create a Feed Importer
3. Add JSON mappings
4. Add the Import URL
5. Use some custom code or perhaps [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) in combination with Tweet module api to schedule and send tweets

Modules:

1. [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds)
2. [Tweet](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter)
3. [JSONPath Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser)
4. [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

Credits: http://www.bariswanschers.com/blog/easily-import-tweets-drupal-using-json-and-feeds

Comment: Thanks but I already found a module called Twitter DB to fetch the tweets. It stores all of them in a database. But I cant figure out how to access the tweets from the database and schedule them . Are there any pre existing modules for it? Or do I need to create a custom one?
Modules:
https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter_db

Comment: Are you trying to "re-tweet" the tweets that the twitter_db module has pulled down from some account? If so, some combination of the suggestion made by undersound would still probably be the solution, although I'm not sure of which api calls are exposed by the module to do the tweeting.

Comment: Ok that information was not in your initial question :)   Looking at twitter_db module you could retrieve the tweets with the _twitter_db_get_last_tweets() function. You wil have to write a custom module for that (https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7)